# Stop range slider after max limit reached native HTML input type slider ANGULAR 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, uislider, rangeslider

I need all sliders (in my case i need 9) but dependent sliders, 
if total reached to maximum value prevent sliders fro moving further!
.

```js
var maxTotal = 150,
  inputs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')),
  getTotal = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      sum += parseInt(input.value, 10);
    });
    return sum;
  },
  maxReached = function(e) {
    var sum = getTotal(),
      target;
    if (sum > maxTotal) {
      target = e.target;
      target.value = target.value - (sum - maxTotal);
      // next line is just for demonstrational purposes
      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = getTotal();
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    // next line is just for demonstrational purposes
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = getTotal();
    return true;
  };

inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('input', maxReached);
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />

<div>total: <strong id="total">0</strong>/150</div>
```

I need to do same in Angular 8 typescript.

Multiple sliders if total of all sliders meet maximum range then preventing slider to move further.

Comment: And have you tried anything with Angular yet? Can you show us?

Comment: @JeremyThille: i have tried it first with ng-5 slider, but on change event i am not able to dynamically change or set MaxLimit so i can prevent slider to move further